# How to access SignalR connection from Azure Service Bus event handler

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a Service Bus event handler in .Net Core 2.1.4 WebAPI listening for and processing events. When it receives an event, I want it to take a User ID from the payload and send a message to all connected SignalR clients for that User.

How do I access SignalR connections from a Service Bus handler?

**Event Handler**

```
private async static Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var receivedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

    await _repository.Add(receivedObject);

    // Send something to all SignalR connections for the user ID in receivedObject
}
```

Comment: Where do you wire up the handler?

Comment: Event Listener code:
https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements/blob/33b062b35a174de918b8e79c50279308266d9fe8/src/Achievements/Achievements/EventListener.cs#L17

Wiring it up:
https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements/blob/af83d2400e2e6f2221221a315083474201fe62db/src/Achievements/Achievements/Program.cs#L18

Comment: I sent you a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wiring up your event listener via Program.cs you should be using an [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Once you do that, your IHostedService will be DI activated and you can access the `IHubContext<AchievementsHub>`.

I sent you a pull request here.

https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements/pull/1/files

Comment: Excellent, this unblocked me. I have not merged your PR only because I had committed changes that caused conflicts, so I took your changes as guidance and made a few tweaks that were specific to my repo (like retrieving connection IDs from a connection map, as this repo has no authentication)

Thanks very much!

Comment: Working repo with setup readme and the above problem solved: https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements

Comment: Why are you looping here https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements/blob/master/src/Achievements/Achievements/Events/EventListener.cs#L81 instead of using the .User feature?

Comment: Also this method is blocking the hub call https://github.com/gcsuk/Achievements/blob/cecb1a59d162272fad5dd6df32ace56644300efa/src/Achievements/Achievements/Hubs/AchievementsHub.cs#L61 , this is an example of something you shouldn't do ever. Blocking like this will stop all other incoming calls to the hub itself.

Comment: Yes I agree, I have deleted the loop you are referring to in your second comment - I had marked it obsolete but there is no need to keep it.
The reason for the loop is the repo has no authentication so I haven't been able to use .Users, maybe I am missing something I will take another look

Comment: To clarify, if I use Users it doesn't error but it also doesn't send the message, whereas looking up the connection works great

Comment: That's because you need to write an IUserIdProvider that reads from the query string and tells SignalR what you want to be the user id. I can send a PR for that if you want.

Comment: If you could that would be great, I had a go at a UserIdProvider when I was stuck but got nowhere